# How to return boolean from Query

Tags: sql-server

I need to check if the user has access based on their roles. (ASP.NET and SQL Server)

```
SELECT rf.ReadAccess
FROM aspnet_Users as u INNER JOIN aspnet_Roles as r ON r.UserID=u.UserID
INNER JOIN RolesByForm as rf ON rf.RoleID=r.RoleID
WHERE u.UserID=@UserID
```

So this gets me close, but this is what I really want. I want forms visible by default, so if there is no record in RolesByForm, it should be "True". But if there is a record it should return based on the ReadAccess field.

How do I get the query to return a Boolean?

Comment: it would be helpful to post your ASP.NET code that uses this query as well.

Comment: If there is no record, there is no record. You shouldn't rely on the SQL query to make your forms visible by default, but use code.

Comment: There is no boolean in TSQL.  However you can return a BIT of 0 or 1 which you can cast in your application with a ternary function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT ReadAccess=CASE rf.ReadAccess WHEN 1 THEN 'True' ELSE 'False' END
FROM aspnet_Users as u INNER JOIN aspnet_Roles as r ON r.UserID=u.UserID
INNER JOIN RolesByForm as rf ON rf.RoleID=r.RoleID
WHERE u.UserID=@UserID
```

And in your .net code write something like:

```
bool result;
bool myBoolean=Boolean.TryParse(dataset["ReadAccess"], out result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
SELECT case count(rf.ReadAccess) when 0 then 'True' else 'False' end ReadAccess 
FROM aspnet_Users as u INNER JOIN aspnet_Roles as r ON r.UserID=u.UserID
INNER JOIN RolesByForm as rf ON rf.RoleID=r.RoleID
WHERE u.UserID=@UserID
```

Answer (score 0):

In .NET the Sql Server field BIT is true or false, so:

```
CAST ( rf.ReadAccess as BIT)
```

Or if ReadAccess is a varchar:

```
CASE ReadAccess
   WHEN 'Something' THEN CAST(1 as bit)
   ELSE CAST (0 as bit)
END
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `rf.ReadAccess` is a bit field (1 or 0) then you want an outer join to capture the non existence of a rolesbyform record.

Something like this perhaps?

```
SELECT distinct isnull(rf.ReadAccess, 1) as ReadAccess
FROM aspnet_Users as u INNER JOIN aspnet_Roles as r ON r.UserID=u.UserID
LEFT OUTER JOIN RolesByForm as rf ON rf.RoleID=r.RoleID
WHERE u.UserID=@UserID
```

Answer (score 0):

You can return 0 (false) and 1 (true). Try this example:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE CheckReadAccess 
@UserID INT
AS

BEGIN
DECLARE @rdAxs VARCHAR(255)

    SELECT @rdAxs = rf.ReadAccess
    FROM aspnet_Users as u INNER JOIN aspnet_Roles as r ON r.UserID=u.UserID
    INNER JOIN RolesByForm as rf ON rf.RoleID=r.RoleID
    WHERE u.UserID=@UserID

    IF @rdAxs IS NULL
        RETURN 0
    ELSE
        RETURN 1

END
```